# Plugin to assign parent category on multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy

I've inherited a mess of a WP site. I need to be able to take 100+ categories and rearrange parent/child relationships. I need something with a UI that will make this easy. Anyone know of a plugin that does this?

Comment: That's perfect! It's so hard to find plugins related to taxonomies or categories via search because of the amount of plugins with these words in it. Put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks!

Comment: Deleted comment - posted answer as requested, happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [Scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu)'s [Term Management Tools](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/term-management-tools/) would be of use to you here, it does various tasks including bulk term management.